# how to match two data frames with unique id to obtain the unmatched dataset in R?

Tags: python, r

How to match two dataframe with unique id to obtain the unmatched data in dataset

> df1
>   id name
>   1  aa
>   2  bb
>   3  cc
>   df2
>   id name
>   1  aa
>   2  bb
>   2  bc
>   3  cc

required output:
id name
2  bc

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple matter if subsetting with a logical index.

```
inx <- !df2$name %in% df1$name
df2[inx, ]
#  id name
#3  2   bc
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
id name
1  aa
2  bb
3  cc
", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
id name
1  aa
2  bb
2  bc
3  cc
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% 
  anti_join(df1)

  id name
1  2   bc
```

## DATA:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
id name
1  aa
2  bb
3  cc", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
id name
1  aa
2  bb
2  bc
3  cc", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```